# Ubuntu 9.10 - Get rid of user list at login screen

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, login-screen

In Ubuntu 9.10, how do I change it so as not to show a list of users at the login screen? I would prefer it to be like 9.04 where you typed in the username, then the password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works (I just did it):

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --set --type boolean /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list true
```

Comment: One slight flaw with this method (Ubuntu's fault, not yours) is that I have to press the down arrow to focus on the login button, I can't just press enter.

Comment: this doesn't work for me for some reason

Answer (score 1):

UG - it appears that the developers have made it even worse in 10.

In my case, I have a lab full of these computers that authenticate off of an LDAP server.  This means any one of 400 users could logon.

What I really want is 2 boxes (one for userid; one for password).   I don't think this is unreasonable...

Answer (score 0):

System > Administration > Login or something like that and then edit those options to your liking. That's probably not exactly it, but I'm pretty sure that should set you on your way.

[I'm in Windows now - that's why I can't check.]

Comment: The option to type username and password has been removed in 9.10 . All that is there is show user list or auto login. (It's Login Screen btw)

Comment: Huh. Ok. That doesn't sound cool. I suspect workarounds will show up on Google shortly.

Comment: I find it hard - no: **very** hard - to believe that.

Comment: @Manni: Install 9.10 and see for yourself...

Comment: I did. You were right. But I **still** find it hard to believe. Why did they do that?

Answer (score 0):

To just change the appearance, check this:
http://lionlix.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/hack-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala-gdm-login-screen/